# Vue components inside cycle

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I think this question a bit silly, but I honestly unable to find it out by myself for now.

My problem is when I'm trying to render bunch of components using

```
…
<tbody v-for="body in bodies">
    <row-c v-for="row in body.rows">
…
```

`bodies` are

```
bodies: [
    {
        someOther: 'smth',
        rows: [
            {title: 'b1r1'},
            {title: 'b1r2'},
            {title: 'b1r3'}
        ]
    },
    {
        someOther: 'smthElse',
        rows: [
            {title: 'b2r1'},
            {title: 'b2r2'},
            {title: 'b2r3'}
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm getting error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: 'TypeError: body is undefined'
```

[CodePen example with error](https://codepen.io/someone_else/pen/NOvZwX)

But without component it works: [CodePen example without error](https://codepen.io/someone_else/pen/KGvjQe).

Of course I've read [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties) reffered from error message, but haven't understand how should I change my code. Give me advice please :)

Thanks in advance.

#### UPD

I've just updated [first codepen](https://codepen.io/someone_else/pen/NOvZwX) according to [Giovane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52793664/1764747), and there are no more errors in it.

Comment: can you add some context as to what `bodies` look like ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you are working with in DOM template you should take a look at the [DOM Template Parsing Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats)

In order to your example to work you should use the attribute `is` in a `<tr>`:

```
<tbody v-for="body in bodies">
  <tr is="row-c" v-for="row in body.rows" v-bind:row="row"></tr>
</tbody>
```

And add the `row` prop in the `row-c`:

```
Vue.component('row-c', {
  props: ['row'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      body: ''
    }
  },
  template: "#row-c-template"
});
```